# C++ constructor not called

Tags: c++, class

In the following code the constructor is called only once (i.e.) when Car() executes. Why is it not called the second time on the statement Car o1(Car())?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class Car
{
public :
   Car()
   {
      std::cout << "Constructor" << '\n';
   }
   Car(Car &obj)
   {
      std::cout << "Copy constructor" << '\n';
   }
};

int main()
{
   Car();
   Car o1(Car()); // not calling any constructor
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `o1` is a function declaration.

Comment: this seems to be correct

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Car o1(Car());
```

This declares a function called `o1` that returns a `Car` and takes a single argument which is a function returning a `Car`. This is known as the [most-vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

You can fix it by using an extra pair of parentheses:

```
Car o1((Car()));
```

Or by using uniform initialisation in C++11 and beyond:

```
Car o1{Car{}};
```

But for this to work, you'll need to make the parameter type of the `Car` constructor a `const Car&`, otherwise you won't be able to bind the temporary to it.

Comment: I just got redirect to this post, may I ask what if I calling it with `Car(Car(Car()))` it didn't invoke any constructor at all, what make it confusing in this case?